# How to work with an external css stylesheet that is messing up my page?

Tags: php, html, css, nvd3.js

I have a webpage written in PHP that displays a table, and I use nvd3 to also show a graph based on the table, however according to this tutorial: http://lsxliron.github.io/nvd3Tutorial/ I should use several css stylesheets, inlcuding

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" />
```

in my head for the page. I also use my own external stylesheet. However the linked one has the code

```
td,th {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 2px
}

td,th {
  padding: 0
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table
}

,th,td {
  border: none
}

*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}
```

in it which messes up my table, short of either not including this stylesheet, explicitly overriding it with my own local css, or making the graph show in a new webpage is there anything I can do? And if those are my only options, how could I override the `*,*:before,*:after` section? It is making my headers off center

Thanks in advance

Edit:
The code being affected by

```
*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}
```

is a div inside of a td used to space out my headings and subheadings, I added `box-sizing: initial` to the div, and it works fine now (everything was shifted to the left before). The `box-sizing inherit` was shrinking the content and increasing the margin.

Comment: Post html code as well.

Comment: Explore using internal and inline styles to specifically over-qualify external styles.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I was sort of hoping I wouldn't have to do that (because I'm lazy)

Comment: Well, you already have an external stylesheet with your own custom rules, so declare your style overrides there and place the `<link>` tag to that file below the `<link>` tag to the external materialize cdn stylesheet. Your custom styles should still over-qualify the materialize rules since they would now be lower down in the "cascade order"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

materialize is not required for NVD3. I would ignore that part of the tutorial unless you want to use Material Design. If you do want to use materialize, then just make your selectors more specific.

e.g.

```
.my-table-wrapper td, .my-table-wrapper th {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll just drop it from my page

Answer (score 0):

1. put your CSS after all others
2. add `!important` to every rule you want to override
3. check with inspector in your favorite browser which rules you have to override additionally and do it also with `!important`
4. remember that the more specific your rule is the higher its priority: `ul li a.menu-link` will override `a.menu-link` for all anchors in ul>li

Example

```
td,th {
  padding: 15px 5px !important;
  display: table-cell !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  border-radius: 2px !important;
}
```

Comment: I can do that, I was just hoping not to have to, oh well. Any ideas on forcing the `box-sizing: inherit` not to function?

Comment: Inherit from what? If you force it to inherit - it will inherit anything that is set = nothing will change. So, additionally you need to force same property at parent level

Comment: Why would you use important! ? Just make the selector more specific. important! is a CSS antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import the materialize fiel in your new css3 file, how you know css work over waterfall, that mean that whe your use import in css on the top of the page, that style will charge in the same css, and beacuse css work over waterfall all the last style overwrite the first style (As long as styles repeat themselves). Go:

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css");

td,th {
 padding: 15px 5px;
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-radius: 2px
 padding: 0
 border: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0
 width: 100%;
}

*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}
```